# Measuring Jamb Depth for New Construction Windows

Tags: framing, windows, siding, flashing, sheathing

I am building a detached garage that is not going to be insulated, however I would like the option to insulate in the future if needed.  Also, I am going to use 7/8" corrugated siding on the outside with j-channel trim to put around the windows on the exterior.

Anyway, I framed the garage walls/window sills with 2x4s and used 7/16" OSB sheathing.  When looking at new construction windows with nailing fins, I am having a difficult time determining what jamb depth I need to use. Despite all the information online, there is not a simple answer on how to measure for new construction.

Is there a minimum jamb depth the window needs to have?  Also, considering my siding choice, is there a maximum jamb depth I should be using?

Anyway, thanks in advance for your answers to a probably very simple question to those who have experience in this realm.

Comment: I don't understand. Install the window. Measure from the interior face of the window to the interior face of the framing. Add for your wall covering. Where are you confused? It has nothing to do with siding.

Comment: @isherwood Why does it have nothing to do with siding?  If I install a window that only protrudes so much from the sheathing and then install j-mold under the window in order to put the corrugated metal siding on, wont that allow for moisture to get under and down behind the siding if the window wasn't extending beyond the j-mold?

Comment: The window flange goes against sheathing. Therefore, the depth of the window is fixed. What you use to cover the walls outside is completely irrelevant. (Siding channel doesn't prevent moisture--your drain plane underneath does.)

Comment: To clarify, if you need deep exterior jambs to accommodate deep siding channel, buy windows which have that. They all mount the same way, though.

Comment: Might help if you'd revise to explain what problem your challenge you're actually trying to solve. That's not clear to me. Provide details about your carpentry plans.

Comment: Having done this wrong once <smile>, the window mounting flange should be attached to the outer-most surface, before the final siding (shingles, cement board, vinyl, etc) is installed.  In your case, that sounds like it's the OSB.  If you were to have another outside layer of material on the house, like a 1" insulating panel on the outside of the OSB (this is where I went wrong), the window flange should be fastened through the insulating board into the OSB and 2x framing for the window opening.  Any shortage on the interior can be made up with jamb extensions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Rule of thumb is 3.5" is about as narrow as you can get with a wide variety of windows **but you really need 4.5-5" to make it look good**.

So if we do the math for yours.   You have ~1/2" (OSB) then 3.5"(2x4) then 1/2" (drywall - could be 3/4" - but let's account for this even if you don't put anything up).    That is a 4.5" jamb and what I would go with.   And honestly on 2x4 walls I am always at 4.5-5".

You tack your window - you can get decent ones with 3" depth.   Here is your [decent el-cheapo](https://www.lowes.com/pd/JELD-WEN-V2500-Vinyl-Double-Pane-Double-Strength-Single-Hung-Window-Rough-Opening-24-in-x-48-in-Actual-23-5-in-x-47-5-in/5000000231).   That means you should have about 1.5" of jamb on the inside of your window.   This is where blinds go and really this depth makes it look professional.

Now you could have windows with a wider jamb but you can't get too crazy with 2x4 walls.   I would do 3.5" width max on the windows.

I have you the 3.5" minimum for your jamb but that half inch jamb showing is not going to look right to the eye... And obviously can install inside mounted blinds.

**Side note:**  Make sure you install your window sills and include in calculations.   For garages a cheap and nice looking window sill can be made by using big box stair treads.   Also your siding has nothing to do with the jamb as the windows are tacked to covering (OSB here) or framing.

Comment: I'm really confused by your answer. I assumed _extension_ jambs--the only kind I've installed over the last 30 years--which don't involve discretionary dimensions. You seem to be describing _full depth_ jambs which would wrap the window, essentially lining the rough opening. Do I misunderstand?

Comment: @isherwood - yea sorry if I am not using terminology you are used to.   We install full depth jambs on the sides and top and the sill on bottom for every install.   I don't think I have done extension jambs in a number of years and only because I messed up or someone else did.

Comment: So they'd go in _before_ the windows, and before the structure is weatherproofed? :O